# MVC website on a shared hosting environment with restricted trust

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shared-hosting, simple-injector

I have a simple MVC 5 web application running on ASP.NET 4.6. The website when configured locally in IIS works, however when the release build is published and uploaded to the shared hosting environment I get an error "Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member"

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc.SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc.SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc.SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.]

My understanding is that MVC web applications need to run with full trust but the hosting provider has indicated that this is not possible and that they have a rule set at machine level that restricts applications to medium trust.

Is there a workaround for this at a code level, I can't believe that to run a simple web application you would need a dedicated web server box that can be configured to have full access.

Is there another IoC container that can be used that doesn't cause this security conflict?

Comment: Since .NET 4.0, Microsoft [has deprecated support for partial trust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218344/264697) in ASP.NET. So even if you would get Simple Injector running, you might run into trouble soon, since Microsoft won't fix any partial trust issues and newly developed logic will not be tested to run in partial trust. As you can read in that link, your hosting provider should *not* run in partial trust.

Comment: In other words, if your shared hosting provider doesn't offer full trust, it is time to look for a new shared hosting provider (or perhaps go with a virtual private server where you can control these settings yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We forget to mark that class with the correct attribute, which now causes this exception. Since Microsoft has deprecated partial trust in ASP.NET web applications, we (the Simple Injector contributors) will probably not invest in this area as well. In other words, don't expect us to fix the bug (soon).

To solve this issue, implement your own `SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver`. Doing this is trivial; it's just a few lines of code that you can copy from Simple Injector's [source code](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/b3b9cfb0abefa4e56c6756f71ea57155cbdf3aab/SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc/SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver.cs).

Comment: Thanks, I've added the dependency resolver class to my project. What attribute does the class need to be tagged with?

Comment: Wouldn't the attribute be ignored? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742902/registering-throws-inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member

Comment: If it's your own code,  I don't think you need any attribute.