# Code Access Security appears to be being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security

I have a simple extension implementation of `WebHostBufferPolicySelector`

```
public class MyBufferPolicySelector : WebHostBufferPolicySelector
{
    private const string _STREAMING_CONTENT_IDENTIFIER = "multipart";

    public override bool UseBufferedInputStream(object hostContext)
    {
        var httpContext = hostContext as HttpContextBase;
        bool? stream = !httpContext?.Request.ContentType.StartsWith(_STREAMING_CONTENT_IDENTIFIER);
        return stream.HasValue ? stream.Value : true;
    }
}
```

But when this dll attempts to load at runtime, I'm seeing the following error

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostBufferPolicySelector.UseBufferedInputStream(System.Object)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Ok, pretty clear, let's dive into [Code Access Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76(v=vs.110).aspx) stuff (I'm on .NET 4.5).

As far as I can tell (from its metadata), `WebHostBufferPolicySelector` and its members are **Transparent**.

Things I've tried:

- Decorating my implementation and its member with **SecurityCritical**
- Decorating my implementation and its member with **SecuritySafeCritical**
- Decorating the assembly my implementation lives in with **[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level2)]**
- Decorating the assembly my implementation lives in with **[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]**
- (Shot in the Dark) Implement the other member `UseBufferedResponseStream`
- (Shot in the Dark) Removed all but a shell implementation that calls `base.RelevantMember`

No matter what, I get the same error message.

### **What else can I check?**

**UPDATE**: Trying `[assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` got me past hitting a security issue with `UseBufferedInputStream`, but I still hit the same error message on a different class within this assembly, this one deriving from `System.Exception`.

---

**More Context**

Some things that *may* be relevant, but I'm unsure how to rule them out:

- This occurs in an ASP.NET Application_Start
- The error occurs when constructing a `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory`, when calling `Ninject.IKernel.Load(<dll containing *MyBufferPolicySelector*>)`

References (among others):

- [Code Access Security, Level 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233102.aspx)
- [Link Demands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzsc022c(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055792/inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member-securityruleset-le)
- [That Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742902/registering-throws-inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member)