# Two connection strings in web.config to one SQL DB work in debug but not when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to add asp identity to a very basic MVC site currently containing a singular table from a SQL database.

The SQL was added as a ADO.NET Entity Data Model, using EF Designer From Database and I can read and write without issue from my MVC site (both locally in development and after being published).

I then added asp.net identity and this added a local DB file which worked.

I then tried to migrate the identity tables across to my main SQL server so that I only have to maintain the one DB (both the hosting of the website and SQL DB are with the same provider).

I have managed to create the tables in the main SQL DB and have added a second connection string to my web.config to allow both asp identity and my existing edmx setup to work (if I try to run asp identity through the EF connection string I get the error "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context."). I then removed the local DB files to be sure.

When testing on my client (with two connection strings) I can create accounts, login and out and use asp.identity as expected and can also see the identity tables in the main SQL DB being populated. I can also use my general EF connection for the core MVC site reading and writing of the DB.

However when I publish to the main site no matter if I call an identity or EF DB function I get the error

> Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

which is displayed over / inline with the rendered page (I've tried turning on custom errors in the web.config but this doesn't appear to give me more details.)

My two connection strings can be seen below (I'm assuming this is where the problem is?) Do I need anything else in the `web.config`? Or am I missing something fundamental?

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="BDIdentityString" connectionString="Data Source=IPADDRESS; Initial Catalog=DBNAME; User ID=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD; Connect Timeout=60;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="BDString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBENTITYNAME.csdl|res://*/Models.DBENTITYNAME.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBENTITYNAME.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=IPADDRESS;initial catalog=DBNAME;user id=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

> UPDATE:

So I finally got custom errors to work (think I had a typo somewhere) and the errors are posted below. As a test I used a backup copy of my project to test again the EF DB queries without the introduction of identity - published it and tested it live. Again it all worked as expected. I then restored my current build with identity added and back to the same issue. (the connection string for EF has remained the same in both versions of the project)

For clarity I am using fasthosts.co.uk and in my testing I am doing this by reading and writing to the live SQL DB hosted with fasthosts from my client. As is the backed up version without identity when published to fasthosts is still able to connect and read / write to the SQL DB.

I'm using their Momentum package so have included a machineKey as required generated from a local IIS server I have. This key is present in both version 1 without identity and version 2 with identity.

I have also tried adding the following to AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

(AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers being recommended by fasthosts for Security Exception Description type errors)

With the customerErrors off I get two different responses based on if I am calling the DB via identity or calling the DB from my EF calls in my MVC code. The errors are as such:

EF error:

```
erver Error in '/' Application.

Operation could destabilize the runtime. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 


[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.FacetDescription.Validate(String declaringTypeName) +70
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.FacetDescription..ctor(String facetName, EdmType facetType, Nullable`1 minValue, Nullable`1 maxValue, Object defaultValue, Boolean isConstant, String declaringTypeName) +103
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.FacetDescriptionElement.CreateAndValidateFacetDescription(String declaringTypeName) +115
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.TypeElement.ResolveTopLevelNames() +119
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.ResolveTopLevelNames() +206
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Resolve() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection) +553
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, IList`1& schemaCollection) +156
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.LoadProviderManifest(XmlReader xmlReader, String location, Boolean checkForSystemNamespace, Schema& schema) +139
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest.Load(XmlReader reader) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbXmlEnabledProviderManifest..ctor(XmlReader reader) +116
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderManifest..ctor(String manifestToken) +37
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c.<GetDbProviderManifest>b__29_0(String s) +25
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +73
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifest(String versionHint) +124
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken) +55

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken) +186
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.Loader.InitializeProviderManifest(Action`3 addError) +312
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.Loader.OnProviderManifestTokenNotification(String token, Action`3 addError) +33
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleProviderManifestTokenAttribute(XmlReader reader) +97
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleAttribute(XmlReader reader) +184
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseAttribute(XmlReader reader) +185
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader) +76
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleTopLevelSchemaElement(XmlReader reader) +37
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.InternalParse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation) +739
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Core.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection) +340
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) +158
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver) +127
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +131
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths) +223
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__1() +14
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +429
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +158
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +79
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__4() +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadAndCheckItemCollection(Func`1 itemCollectionLoader) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<.ctor>b__3() +21
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +429
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +158
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +79
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required) +95
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InitializeMappingViewCacheFactory(DbContext owner) +46
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) +575
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() +65
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +506
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +20
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) +108
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) +72
   HotBrewCrew.Controllers.HomeController.Register(interested_parties fromForm) in C:\Users\ewilson\Documents\Development\HotBrewCrew\HotBrewCrew\Controllers\HomeController.cs:26
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9839161
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

And Identity error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1<T>.UnsafeOnCompleted(System.Action)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1<T>.UnsafeOnCompleted(System.Action)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1<T>.UnsafeOnCompleted(System.Action)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.PasswordSignInAsync(String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean shouldLockout) +0
   HotBrewCrew.Controllers.<Login>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ewilson\Documents\Development\HotBrewCrew\HotBrewCrew\Controllers\AccountController.cs:74
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9839161
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.3928.0
```

> Update 2

This could be a trust issue with fasthosts. I've just built a out of the box MVC site with identity enabled. Changed the connection string to point to the SQL DB - again works from development environment (with details registered from main project development testing) but fails when pushed live with no other changes.

I will endeavour to ask the hosting provider but am not 100% convinced this is my only / or actual problem as EF works without identity just not with identity installed in the project.

Comment: Post the actual exception text. Have you tried debugging your code? The problem may simply be due to an incorrect IP

Comment: The "Data Source" may require a server name and instance.  Use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and check the login window.  The Server and Instance will be in the login Window.  Also check if the credentials is Windows. To use a remote database (not on same machine) you have to be able to connect between two different windows machines.  So two machines need to be in the same group to.  So you have to create a windows group.  It is also better to use a Windows credential instead of a user name and password.  Create a user group account on local and remote machine and add all users to group.

Comment: Thanks for having an initial look - I've managed to get the csustomErrors working and have updated the post - the development and live SQL DB are the same. This works from the development environment to live DB just not live environment to live DB (live environment and DB provider are the same provider)

Comment: This stab in the dark says edit your web.config https://cslanet.com/old-forum/12744.html

Comment: This appears to be a better explained answer. If only I could understand it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742902/registering-throws-inheritance-security-rules-violated-while-overriding-member

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I had already tried the first option but get the message from the provider "This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file." so setting trust in web.config to full is out (it's a shared cluster so no access to IIS controls). I have read the second one earlier and like yourself struggling to understand it. Will have another go.

Answer (score 0):

As expected the limitation was with https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/ - Moving my site with no code changes (other than the SQL connection string to reflect the new SQL server) with provider https://hostinguk.net/ the site worked without issue.

Comment: Indeed recent versions of .NET require full trust. Many low budget shared host providers still block this for some unknown reason. I remember seeing a statement that there is no reason for doing so.